# This is an algorithm design problem, which requires constant time. I thought of how to use constant time to solve this problem

Tags: algorithm

The following questions assume the RAM model. Under this model, we can execute the logic of two O(log n)-bit integers in constant time
Edit and arithmetic operations, and can also read/write consecutive O(logn) bits of any memory address in constant time.
Here are 2 questions:

Given a random 0/1 sequence B[0, n-1]. That is, for 0≤i≤n-1, B[i]=0 or 1. Solve the following problems:.
(a) Design the data structure and algorithm, use the smallest possible space, and calculate the number of 1s in B[0, i] in constant time.
(b) Design the data structure and algorithm, use the smallest possible space, and calculate the i-th 1 position in B in constant time.

Comment: look at this for a start https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: but in general this kind of question will not get an answer, SO is not an assignment writing service. Try something, post code when u get stuck

Comment: For (a), does it mean that we can do some preprocessing in O(n), and then answer the query in constant time?

Comment: i dont see i can count n bits in constant time, when n can be huge