# An algorithm problem about 0's and 1's sequence

Tags: algorithm

The following questions are assumed to be from the RAM model. In this model, we can perform logical and arithmetic operations of two o (log n) bit integers in constant time, and read / write consecutive o (log n) bits of any memory address in constant time.

Given random 0 / 1 sequence B [0, ... , n-1], that is, for 0 ≤ I ≤ n-1, B [i] = 0 or 1. Solve the following questions:

1.Design the data structure and algorithm, and use the smallest space as possible to calculate the number of 1 in B [0, i] in a constant time.

2.Design the data structure and algorithm, use the smallest possible space as possible, and calculate the position of the ith i in B in a constant time.

3.Implement the algorithm of the above questions 1 and 2 using the given input data (file: test_100 MB.txt)

My main puzzle is that this problem can be solved in a constant time? Given a random sequence, isn't it necessary to traverse all data at least once? Isn't time complexity O(n)? Or do I have a misunderstanding about the RAM model in the topic? If there is an algorithm in constant time, please point me out, thank you very much.

Because the same problem has been released, I didn't see it before, so now I have closed this question

Comment: This seems to be the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254759/this-is-an-algorithm-design-problem-which-requires-constant-time-i-thought-of . Perhaps you should ask your teacher or teaching assistant to clarify the problem?

Comment: @StephenC O(log n) bits per memory cell is a common theoretical model of computers for doing complexity theory called the "word model" or "transdichotomous model".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question allows for preprocessing. I.e., you can parse the array and populate some data structure. After doing so, you should be able to return the count of 1s in [0,i] in constant time for any i.